# MySQL two (almost) identical table merge the values and default unique values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union, rdbms

I have two almost identical MySQL tables besides a date column, and I would like to merge them with a select query to create a final table displaying both dates.

If there is a unique `acc_id` in one table -> i want to default the amount in the other to `0`.

Here is an example of what i mean:

`Table1:`

| id | acc_id | name | aug_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | name1 | 100 |
| 2 | 456 | name2 | 200 |
| 3 | 333 | name3 | 300 |

`Table2:`

| id | acc_id | name | sep_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | name1 | 200 |
| 2 | 456 | name2 | 300 |
| 3 | 444 | name4 | 400 |

`Merged table:`

| acc_id | name | aug_amount | sep_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | name1 | 100 | 200 |
| 456 | name2 | 200 | 300 |
| 333 | name3 | 300 | 0 |
| 444 | name4 | 0 | 400 |

Is there a way i can achieve this with a singular SQL query? I've been playing around for a while but i cant seem to crack it.

Help appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is ID an actual column in those tables? If so, what is the logic for deciding which ID to use when the acc_ids are different?

Comment: `id` is the PK used for each table - generated when new accounts are entered. `acc_id` is the FK connected to an accounts table which holds more data

Comment: Where did id 4 come from?  It's not in either of your source tables

Comment: Good point.. thats a mistake on my part. I think the final merged table shouldn't have an `id` field. - Im going to edit the question

Comment: Are you looking for a solution which will do this repeatedly over time, or a once-off cleanup operation? The simplest solution in my mind would be to make the table with the schema you desire, and then use `INSERT ... SELECT` from both of the old tables. You can then either live happily with newly-assigned user ids, or you can keep junction tables for the old user ids (mapped from the new ones) for some legacy support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the PK column, here is one solution where we union the two tables and then select from it:

```
select acc_id, name, sum(aug_amount) as aug_amount, sum(sep_amount) as sep_amount
from (
  select acc_id, name, aug_amount, 0 as sep_amount
  from table1
  union
  select acc_id, name, 0, sep_amount
  from table2
)z
group by acc_id, name
order by name;
```

| acc_id | name | aug_amount | sep_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | name1 | 100 | 200 |
| 456 | name2 | 200 | 300 |
| 333 | name3 | 300 | 0 |
| 444 | name4 | 0 | 400 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eJHXyC9PyTyDgGzDSpRXQx/0)